# Cannot add features to an Azure 2012 R2 VM

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to install .Net 3.5 through Roles & Features. The message appears:

> Do you need to specify an alternate source path? One or more
>   installation selections are missing source files on the destination
>   server. The server will try to get missing source files from Windows
>   Update, or from a location that is specified by Group Policy. You can
>   also click the “Specify an alternate source path” link on this page to
>   provide a valid location for the source files.

I selected Install and it failed complaining it could not find the files.

The VM is "Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter" from the Gallery

Where are the source files? Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue. Evidently a recent security update prevents .Net 3.5 being installed.  The fix is to use Windows Update to add more recent patches.

Answer seen at https://superuser.com/questions/789193/how-do-i-enable-the-net-framework-3-5-on-an-azure-vm-created-from-a-windows-ser

Thanks Jeff (https://superuser.com/users/1071/jeff-moser)